# How can i retrieve a specific data from a firebase child node into Android studio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

```
referenc2= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messageCounter").child("node"); 
referenc2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { 
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) { 
    String count= Integer.parseInt(snapshot.child("cnt").getValue(String.class)); 
  } 
  @Override public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { 
  } 
});
```

I need to retrieve the value stored inside the cnt node into a variable in android studio. can anyone help?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If so, please show us the minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck. If not, I recommend starting with the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) and [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/) for Android developers.

Comment: referenc2= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messageCounter").child("node");  referenc2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

              String  count=  Integer.parseInt(snapshot.child("cnt").getValue(String.class));


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

Comment: Please don't add blocks of code in comments. Instead, use the edit link under your question, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up (which I did for you now).

Comment: Your code has `messageCounter`, while your JSON has `RouteCounter`. Since those don't match, your code won't be reading the value your JSON shows.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get value of specific node or child node like this

Here if you want to get child **node(address)** value. You can get it in this way

```
DatabaseReference db= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("RouteCounter").child("node");

    
    db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String email = userSnapshot.child("cnt").getValue(String.class);
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
```

Comment: i tried it but didn't work, the app keeps stopping now

Comment: @chamalpeiris can you approve the answer.

Comment: @chamalpeiris hello?